# Using cmake to cross compile multiple libraries and apps

Tags: c, cmake

I'm having issues with cmake while trying to cross compile an existing, large codebase. Our current build system uses a proprietary IDE that is causing a large number of issues -- so we're trying to move away.

I've distilled this to the simplest example I can.

Note: This all works when I don't use the toolchain option with cmake. I can get this to compile and run if just using the native toolchain.

I don't currently suspect issues with the toolchain file for cmake. I have used it to get OpenCV to compile -- with some hacking OpenCV.

The error that I get when trying to cross compile is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/MY_USER/Desktop/test_app/build-test_app
Scanning dependencies of target liba
[ 25%] Building C object libs/liba/CMakeFiles/liba.dir/liba.c.o
Linking C shared library libliba.so
[ 25%] Built target liba
Scanning dependencies of target libb
[ 50%] Building C object libs/libb/CMakeFiles/libb.dir/libb.c.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `libs/liba/liba.a', needed by `libs/libb/liblibb.so.1.0.0'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [libs/libb/CMakeFiles/libb.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It's like it's looking for a static version of the library, but I've configured it to use shared objects when calling cmake:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 ..
```

I've included all of the files in the test project below. This is the same issue I run into when trying to get the larger project to compile.

Project structure:

```
test_app
├── app
│   ├── appa
│   │   ├── appa.c
│   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── liba
│   │   └── liba.h
│   ├── libb
│   │   └── libb.h
│   └── libc
│       └── libc.h
└── libs
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── liba
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── liba.c
    ├── libb
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── libb.c
    └── libc
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── libc.c
```

Top level CMakeLists.txt

```
project(test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt/test")
set(INSTALL_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_EXECUTE)

set(TEST_VERSION 1.0.0)
set(TEST_MAJOR_VERSION 1)

set(TEST_GLOBAL_INCLUDES
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CROSS_TARGET}/usr/pkg/include>
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)

set(TEST_GLOBAL_LIB_PATHS
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CROSS_TARGET}/usr/pkg/include>
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)

add_subdirectory(libs)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

app/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(appa)
```

app/appa/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(appa)

add_executable(appa appa.c)

target_include_directories(appa PUBLIC ${TEST_GLOBAL_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(appa libc)

# Set version information
set_target_properties(appa PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${TEST_VERSION}
)

# set install destination and permissions
install(
    TARGETS appa
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
    PERMISSIONS ${INSTALL_PERMISSIONS}
)
```

app/appa/appa.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <libc/libc.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello world: %d\n", libc_function(2));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

include/liba/liba.h

```
#pragma once

int liba_function(int a);
```

include/libb/libb.h

```
#pragma once

int libb_function(int a);
```

include/libc/libc.h

```
#pragma once

int libc_function(int a);
```

libs/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(liba)
add_subdirectory(libb)
add_subdirectory(libc)
```

libs/liba/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(libliba)

add_library(liba liba.c)

target_include_directories(liba PUBLIC ${TEST_GLOBAL_INCLUDES})

# Set version information
set_target_properties(liba PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${TEST_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${TEST_MAJOR_VERSION}
)

# set install destination and permissions
install(
    TARGETS liba
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
    PERMISSIONS ${INSTALL_PERMISSIONS}
)
```

libs/liba/liba.c

```
#include <liba/liba.h>

int liba_function(int a)
{
    return a * a;
}
```

libs/libb/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(liblibb)

add_library(libb libb.c)

target_include_directories(liba PUBLIC ${TEST_GLOBAL_INCLUDES})

# Set version information
set_target_properties(libb PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${TEST_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${TEST_MAJOR_VERSION}
)

target_link_libraries(libb liba)

# set install destination and permissions
install(
    TARGETS libb
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
    PERMISSIONS ${INSTALL_PERMISSIONS}
)
```

libs/libb/libb.c

```
#include <liba/liba.h>
#include <libb/libb.h>

int libb_function(int a)
{
    return liba_function(a) * liba_function(a);
}
```

libs/libc/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(liblibc)

add_library(libc libc.c)

target_include_directories(libc PUBLIC ${TEST_GLOBAL_INCLUDES})

# Set version information
set_target_properties(libc PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${TEST_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${TEST_MAJOR_VERSION}
)

target_link_libraries(libc libb)

# set install destination and permissions
install(
    TARGETS libc
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
    PERMISSIONS ${INSTALL_PERMISSIONS}
)
```

libs/libc/libc.c

```
#include <libb/libb.h>
#include <libc/libc.h>

int libc_function(int a)
{
    return libb_function(a) * libb_function(a);
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a separate `project` for each library and application, make a single "root" project that all CMake-files in the subdirectories are part of. In other words, keep `project(test)` in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, and remove (or comment out) all other `project` commands. Please try that and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried. I get the same result. It will work with the native toolchain, but fails when cross compiling.

Comment: Hmm... Reading the error messages closer, it seems there's some mixup between static and shared libraries (CMake creates targets for shared libraries, but the dependencies are static libraries). Perhaps you should state explicitly what kind of library you want to make in the [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) command? As in `add_library(liba SHARED liba.c)`

Comment: Another thing to try is to rename the libraries, to plain `a`, `b` and `c`? As CMake will automatically add the `lib` prefix on POSIX systems for you. I'm guessing this because `liblibb.so` depends on plain `liba.a` and not `libliba.a` (or the correct `libliba.so`).

Comment: A fact, that CMake cannot find things (`liba.so` in given case) which it produces, usually indicates that project's code does some **wrong things**. I don't see these things in your code, so it is probably the **toolchain** which is written wrong. Without viewing its code it is difficult to be more detailed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are correct! I feel like an idiot for assuming all was well with the toolchain file. I forgot I had placed set(CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".a") when compiling opencv to get all the third party image libs to link correctly.